# How to handle mouse event in stateless component in React

Tags: reactjs

All:

I wonder if I use stateless component, how can I handle mouse event to change component style, for example:

```
const Com = (props) => {
    var hltStyle = false;
    function highlight(){
        // I do not know what put here
    }

    var hltStyle = {
        backgroundColor: !hltStyle?"lightgreen": "tomato"
    }

    return (
        <div style={hltStyle} onMouseOver={ highlight } >HOVER ME</div>
    )
}
```

What I want just hover this component and change background color. There is some other logic inside highlight, that is why I can not simply use CSS

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that using something like this

```
const Com = () => {
        function over(e){
                e.target.style.backgroundColor="red";
        }
        function out(e){
                e.target.style.backgroundColor='';
        }
        return <div onMouseOver={over} onMouseOut={out}>HOVER ME </div>;
}
```

Anyway, if you feel that you need to declare some variables to use them as the state, you should use a normal component instead of a stateless one.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/44851/)

Answer (score 0):

What about using classic CSS for simple hover effects?

```html
<div class="el-to-hover"></div>
```

somewhere in css-file:

```css
.el-t-hover {
   background: transparent
   transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}
.el-to-hover:hover {
   background: red
}
```